# I want to re define a variable in php, with the php if function

Tags: php, variables

Okay, so I want to re define a variable with something like,

```
if($query =="foo")
$query= "apple"
else $query=""
end
```

But I'm sure this is broken in same way, keep getting a 500 error.

Comment: Could you add your real code to the question?

Comment: Try with `;` at the end of statements (also, it's `endif`). Some PHP tutorial could help though.

Comment: This is going to be part of a new file, for filtering out querys I don't want to run against my SQL server, so far, this is the only code thats in the file, I can include a blank space?

Comment: thanks,  X.L.Ant I will try that.

Comment: If by "that" you mean read a tutorial, be my guest. If you mean adding `;` all over the place, I'm afraid you'll be back in 5 minutes with another problem.

Comment: Why do you have `end` there?  Why do you not have `{}` or `;`?

Comment: @X.L.Ant: `endif;` is only used when you use `if():` (note the colon).  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!

Comment: got rid of else and the end, added the ; after the if.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Of course you're right, I guess I got blinded by the other mistakes :)

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat I'm kinda newish to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use brackets, and semicolons.

```
if ($query == "foo") {
$query = "apple";
}
else {
$query = null;
}
```

Comment: Indentation wouldn't be a bad plan either.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best and more correct syntax that you can use there is:

```
if ($query == "foo"){
    $query = "apple";
}else{
    $query = "";
}
```